# Using new <class Name> (new <class name>(file name))

Tags: java

inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));

In the above line of code, I didn't understand having new FileReader in new BufferReader? Would someone help me understand the logic of the code?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What is unclear? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileReader.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically `new FileReader("xanadu.txt")` creates a new object of type `FileReader` and this type of reader is used to read character files. I would also suggest to read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) to get more information of the different existing readers which are available in the JDK and also fulfill different purpose. E.g. you could also use `FileInputStream` instead of `FileReader` if you want to read raw bytes instead of characters.

If you create a new `BufferedReader` you have to pass during initialization an object of type `Reader`. The `BufferedReader` extends the passed reader with buffering functionality. I would recommend [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-buffered-reader) for more information on how this works with different `Reader` implementations. Finally I recommend to take a look in the Java docs to get more knowledge on the [Buffered Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and the available methods which "extend" the `Reader` you passed to the `BufferedReader` with additional functionality.

And even more general

`new ClassNameA (new ClassNameB(parameter))`

this construct does nothing more than => create an object of type `ClassNameB` and pass it through the constructor during initialization to a newly created object of type `ClassNameA`. So basically you are creating two objects and pass the first one through the constructor of the second one. The initialization order is by brackets from inner to outer.